# Printer on board of the ISS?

Tags: iss, equipment

Every now and then you can see crewmembers carrying paper manuals or notes around. Is this all pre-printed on earth / handwritten or is there actually a printer on the ISS?

Comment: They can always 3d-print their manuals ;)

Comment: You mean like in Braille? :-)

Comment: Like printing press dies. extruded or embossed lettering :)

Comment: ...or maybe @SF. meant [this thing](http://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/nasa-sending-3d-printer-to-iss/) at first but then liked the embosser idea better?

Comment: @uhoh: I meant this. But if you print words alone, the thing would fall apart. Instead, you can print the sheet, leaving the words out. A spray paint stencil would be a more appropriate analogy.

Comment: related [question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/15498/12102)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, according to [Robert Frost](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-laser-or-an-inkjet-printer-on-the-International-Space-Station) , NASA Instructor and Flight Controller, the ISS has a Epson Stylus Color 800 mounted on the aft wall of Destiny.

[image]

<sup>Epson Stylus Color 800 from 1996</sup>

The printer is also visible in [the International Space Station Panoramic Tour](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/International_Space_Station/Highlights/International_Space_Station_panoramic_tour) provided by ESA.
[image]

Comment: I don't actually see a printer inside that red circle. Can you point to it? [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PoI5l.jpg) from the [3D interactive walkthrough](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/International_Space_Station/Highlights/International_Space_Station_panoramic_tour) from photos by record-holding ESA astronaut [Samantha Cristoforetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samantha_Cristoforetti) taken in June 2015 look very different. While Robert Frosts's Quora post is dated March 2015, where is that photo from?

Comment: @mins. See edit. Also, thanks for the link, great ISS resource.

Comment: Looks like they bought a new printer when they cleaned up. It looks like a complete, enclosed paper cassette sticking out of the top, rather than the open tray on the Epson. I wonder if this is now a special zero-G-friendly printer. Can't use gravity feed anymore!

Comment: @uhoh in theory you could spin up the entire station anytime you want to print.

Comment: related [question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/15498/12102)

Comment: @JanDvorak now why didn't I think of that? I was going to put it in a giant hamster cage along with an [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

Comment: I can actually imagine an astronaut grabbing the printer, then spinning in the middle of the station, holding the printer in outstretched arms...