# Was this printer shown the ISS in 2015 built specially to work in microgravity?

Tags: iss, microgravity, equipment

The question [Printer on board of the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15487/12102) was [answered](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15492/12102) in the affirmative. This *seems* to be a printer with a special paper cassette on "top" to feed the paper, since gravity feed is not going to work. But is it really? Or is that the "receiver" and somebody hid the blank paper cassette which seems to be missing from the bottom?

Has this printer been specially built to work in microgravity? If so, by whom? What *kind* of printer is it (bubble jet? laser? etc.) Does the ink or toner feed also need special considerations to work in microgravity?

**edit:** For any piece of equipment to be shipped to the ISS and installed on board, it must go through a significant amount of testing for safety and reliability. So if there is a printer there, then there must be some documented evidence (beyond personal opinion) that it's going to really work reliably - and is not expected to cause problems - in the ISS environment. I think it would be remarkable that an un-modified, off-the-shelf 99 or 49 dollar printer was just put in a launch vehicle, subjected to all sorts of vibrations, then operated in microgravity and reduced pressure in close proximity to humans without any modification. *Was it*?

Screenshot from the [3D interactive walkthrough](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/International_Space_Station/Highlights/International_Space_Station_panoramic_tour) from photos by record-holding ESA astronaut [Samantha Cristoforetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samantha_Cristoforetti) taken in June 2015

[image: printer on the international space station?]

Zoomed and rotated from here (printer on lower-left):

[image]

"Reblogged" from @ForgeMonkey 's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15492/12102)

[image: reblogged]

Comment: So, with all the added cost and hassle of printing in zero g, the difficulty of getting ink into space and so forth, the ISS isn't totally paperless? I'd take a kindle in space over paper any day. Anyone know WHY there is a printer?

Comment: @wedstrom I think it's used for printing out boarding passes for the flight home. You know, with increased security and all these days.

Comment: @wedstrom -- Whenever I'm working on a computer, I have at least two of four very old-fashioned devices right next to the computer: A green engineering pad and/or my unlined Moleskine notebook, and a very nice mechanical pencil and/or a very nice pen. When I'm debugging the blank sheet of paper, I want a blank sheet of paper rather than a computer facsimile of one.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'd think twice about that workflow if notebook paper was $10,000 a kilogram...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's an Epson Stylus Color 800 - a pretty standard inkjet printer (a laser printer would be a nightmare - all that fine toner dust!)

Here's an example of an Earthly one from a 1998 page of the [Washington Apple Pi Journal](http://www.wap.org/journal/epson/epson.html):

[image]

The ink cartridges don't care about gravity - they work by capillary attraction from a storage sponge in the cartridge, and then vaporisation at the print head. You can run print heads at whatever angle you like here on Earth, and they work just fine in microgravity, but some optimisation **could** have been carried out, as per [this paper from RIT.edu](http://taga.rit.edu/2010/nasa.html). That optimisation is for drop speed, size and shape, and not essential for operation.

The only challenging bit is the paper feed, as it is usually gravity fed from the top, letting the paper sit in place until the pickup and feed rollers are in use. The roller friction itself is sufficient once the paper is pulled into the feed path, but without gravity this may not work - compare the two pictures to see the additional section which feeds the paper in the absence of gravity.

**To answer the actual question:**

The printer was not built specifically for space, but there are modifications to ensure it works in space. The obvious one being the paper feed unit, but others are likely, such as optimisation of print heads and strengthening of ribbon cables etc to cope with the vibration of launch.

Comment: OK - So is the paper feed a specially designed modification for microgravity? If so, can I read about it somewhere? Is *Epson 800* coming from the Quora answer by Robert Frost, or do you have a better source? Also, can I have some link to a source for the statement that standard Epson ink cartridges work in microgravity and zero gravity? Capillary action works well in capilaries, but what about the reservoir holding the floating globule of ink? I mean in order to drink the fresh-brewed espresso on the ISS they had to use specially designed cups.

Comment: @uhoh Well, they certainly have *something* non-standard covering the paper feeder, at least. No telling from the picture what that does, though.

Comment: Thanks - I've added an **edit** to the question. The info on the sponge was interesting (someone has removed several comments without a trace or explanation) but I need an independent source that shows that they really do work in microgravity - ind if they do with, or without modification.

Comment: There are no floating globules. The ink permeates a sponge in the cartridge, as anyone who has used a refill kit can tell you.

Comment: @JerardPuckett: That depends on the model. Ink in my old HP cartridges definitely sloshed around. But these were times where a cartridge could support a good 1000 pages of prints, containing some 30ml of ink or so. I wonder if the astronauts must replace their cartridges whenever their due date is past or print counter runs out, regardless of their actual state and ink level... but AFAIK Epson has been shying away from such nefarious practices.

Comment: @JerardPuckett (and Rory) I found [this hpinkcartridges.co.uk article](http://www.hpinkcartridges.co.uk/technology-blog/2012/05/hp-introduces-nano-sponge) about the sponges. So it's also the *hydrophobicity* of the "sponge" material, not just capillary action that "pushes" the ink out. The second image is [pretty darn dramatic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5I5jm.jpg) - showing the black ink crowding down towards "EXIT" while the remainder of the sponge as totally dry and free of any ink. Nice! I'm on vacation - as soon as I get some I'm going to pop a few open!

Comment: The paper isn't gravity fed. Gravity is what holds the paper in the feed mechanism. There is usually a roller that will begin rotating and then lever down onto the surface of the paper. It then gains traction on the top-most sheet, which slides against the next sheet. The entire stack is usually under that roller. So, all that would be necessary is something to keep the paper from floating away. (NB: This is my experience with many varieties of printer - I know nothing about this particular one).

Answer (score 5):

There are no modern printers with gravity fed paper input.  The paper is always "picked" by a roller on a bar that is mechanically pressed against the paper.  Output is the problem. Printers rely on gravity to hold the paper in the output tray.  The ISS printer is modified to enclose the output trays.  The input tray is also enclosed because the roller pressure is intentionally weak on top loaders until the printer performs a paper feed. This allows users to add paper easily.
Older inkjet cartridges used sponges, newer ones use fiber. The cartridge fiber is saturated with ink when new, there is no ink sloshing around in the cartridge. Canon and HP inkjets use heat to shoot out ink drops, Epsons use piezoelectric squirt guns.

Comment: That's a good point - probably easier to make hydrophobic fibers than a hydrophobic sponge! I wonder if they are still referred to "sponges" even though they're made from fiber. I wish someone would post something like [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5I5jm.jpg) from [hpinkcartridges.co.uk](http://www.hpinkcartridges.co.uk/technology-blog/2012/05/hp-introduces-nano-sponge) so everyone could see what this whole ink in microgravity discussion is about!

Answer (score 4):

My brother just pointed out that:

> In October 1998, the Epson Stylus Color 800 became the first ever color printer to be used in space when it was installed in the Space Shuttle Discovery for the 92nd space shuttle mission (STS-95). The printer performed so well that Epson was subsequently selected as the printer supplier for the International Space Station.

From [(Epson) MILESTONE EPSON IMAGING TECHNOLOGIES AND PRODUCTS](http://www.epson.co.in/epson_india/explore_epson/mediacentre/company_information/milestone_products/printer.page?pno=2&tabname=&subcat=)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The other answers covered what model of printer, but I have insight into its ease of use:

During Expedition 51 in 2017, the crew reported difficulties getting the printer to function properly. It played out in an amusingly frustrating series of crew notes documenting the malfunctions, and culminated with the crew celebrating the aging printer's EOL with the following paraphrased note:

> Before we shut off [the printer] for the last time, I told him he was going
> to the trash and that he would burn...

The printer was deorbited on Orbital ATK OA-7, and did indeed burn with the rest of the trash.

So it would appear that the user experience with desktop printers in space and on earth is very similar, but with a less spectacular means of disposal available for earthbound printers.