# Music played in space

Tags: iss, space-shuttle

Besides the Curiosity rovers's rendition of Happy Birthday and Chris Hadfields guitar playing aboard the ISS, is there a list of music played in space live (robots playing music counts too)?

Note: Music added during a Livestream (ie falcon heavy) does not count.

Comment: I almost made an edit changing "played" to "performed" because I assumed you didn't want to include people playing music on their MP3 players or laptops. But when I saw "robots playing music" I decided I'm not sure what you mean yet. Do you want to exclude the laptops and MP3 players from your list?

Comment: @uhoh Well I assume that astronauts on the ISS listen to music all the time but that's not what I'm going for--but calling curiosity's happy birthday a performance is up to interpretation :) I just wanted to make sure to include events like curiosity's happy birthday.

Comment: @uhoh *astronaut responds with picture of iTunes account*

Comment: There is one music that always plays in space: 4'33 by John Cage :)

Comment: Space Oddity and Is there Life On Mars? from the Roadster?

Comment: Let's not forget "The Internationale" played from Luna 10 in orbit of the Moon.

Comment: @Siegfried I love it!

Comment: Wouldn’t be surprised if they played something in MIR during the jean Michel jarr oxygène concert but I can’t tell...

Comment: I think anyone who didn't listen to [Chris Hadfield's awesome rendition of Space Oddity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaOC9danxNo) is severely missing out. It's not just the guitar - the vocals, the video, it's a professional recording! Allegedly David Bowie fought with his publisher to keep this recording available on Youtube.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ellen Ochoa, space flautist.

STS-56, launched April 1993.

[image]

Cady Coleman, space flautist.

Expedition 27, March 2011.

[image]

Carl Walz, space keyboardist

Expedition 4, Dec 2001 - June 2002

[image]

Ed Lu, space keyboardist

Expedition 7, 2003

Thomas Pesquet, space saxophonist

Expedition 50/51, Nov 2016 to June 2017

[image]

Don Pettit, space vacuum-cleaner-ist/didgeridooist

Expedition 6 Nov 2002 to May 2003, Expedition 30/31 Dec 2011 to July 2012

[image]

Ron McNair, space saxophonist

STS-41B, Feb 1984.

[image]

Wally Schirra / Tom Stafford, [bells and harmonica](https://airandspace.si.edu/stories/editorial/tom-stafford%E2%80%99s-jingle-bells-and-wally-schirra%E2%80%99s-harmonica)

Gemini 6, Dec 1965

[image]

Naoko Yamazaki on koto

[image]

Soichi Noguchi on ryuteki

[image]

[Useful information on crew wakeup music](https://history.nasa.gov/wakeup%20calls.pdf)

Comment: Flautists eh? Youd think with aeronautics potentially crossing over with military somebody wouldve tried a trumpet or taps.

Comment: It's possible, I'm still looking.

Comment: Nothing wrong with flutes! I enjoyed playing for 4 years-- I kind of want to ask which instruments wouldnt function in zero gravity now. Honestly curious which mechanical instruments have reliance on gravity.

Comment: I love that picture of Ellen with the checklists flying around her.

Comment: The main thing I love about ISS photos-- especially the interior-- is how many things you notice when you zoom in that youd absolutely miss on a precusory glance! A ziploc of bandaids attached to the wall behind the keyboardist for example. I wonder how many stubbed toes and 0g accidents before that happened ha!

Comment: RTFM = Reading The Flute Manual

Comment: Reading The Flute Music

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Off the top of my head all I can think of is something like a [rainstick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainstick) or the hammers of a piano that have a *direct* reliance on gravity. Edit: [it's already been asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64524/what-are-the-limitations-of-performing-music-in-space) on Physics SE.

Comment: Draining the spit out of wind instruments might get tricky, so you could play a trumpet, but perhaps for only a few hours ...

Comment: As a note: my wife, a professional flutist, tells me there is a lot of contention over the use of "flautist" vs "flutist" in the USA (http://flutetoday.com/flutist-flautist-flute-player/). Coincidentally, she teaches at Ronald McNair middle school.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 very interesting!  I had to look up how to spell it....

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I've got to imagine that a trumpet would be *terribly* loud in the limited space. Additionally, see JCRM's comment on the spit...

Comment: Somebody should edit the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohner) adding that a Hohner harmonica was in space with Gemini 6.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The classic non electronic piano would need gravity as its means of return its hammers to a state of rest. The iron frame of the piano would be to heavy for a transport to the ISS anyway.

Answer (score 12):

Quite recently, Alexander Gerst performed on a tablet, using a Launchpad-like app:

> On 20 July 2018 around 21:50 local time, ESA astronaut Alexander Gerst welcomed the legendary electronic band Kraftwerk and 7500 visitors to the Jazz Open Festival on Stuttgart's Schlossplatz – live from the International Space Station, where he will live and work until mid-December 2018.

Answer (score 4):

An addition to Organic Marble's answer.

Alexander Ivanchenkov plays guitar

Salyut-6, 1978

[image: Ivanchenkov plays Guitar]

Volkov plays guitar and Krikalev plays (an improvised?) drum.

Mir, 1989

[image: Volkov plays guitar]

Talgat Musabaev playes *another* guitar

Mir, 1998

[image: Musabaev playes guitar]

There WAS a guitar on Salyut-7, but I can't find a picture right away.

Comment: Great! I've just asked [How did Sergei Krikalev get (or build) the drum he is shown playing here?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30340/12102)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers:

- **2013** Luca Parmitano played synthesizer keyboard from ISS in duplex with Didier Marouani live concert (2:37 in the following video)
- **2018** Andrew Feustel and Scott Tingle play guitars
  [image]
- **2018** "international space band". Anton Shkaplerov and Oleg Artemyev learned to play Peruvian pipes; Andrew Feustel and Scott Tingle performed with the guitar, and Richard Arnold with the Hawaiian drum
  [image]
- **2019** If robots playing music counts too, then this (perhaps) deserves mentioning as well: the first space DJ, Luca Parmitano [performed](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.space.com/amp/first-dj-in-space-astronaut-luca-parmitano.html) a 12-minute DJ set from a tablet with built-in DJ software. 14:16, 16:03 in the following video

Answer (score 0):

SpaceX's Falcon Heavy launch carried a Tesla roadster that was playing 'Life on Mars'. Link: [Here](https://consequenceofsound.net/2018/02/elon-musks-latest-spacex-rocket-is-soundtracked-by-an-infinite-loop-of-david-bowies-space-oddity/)

Comment: As I posted in my question, this doesn't count as it's not preformed. The music was added during the FH livestream.

Comment: @Dragongeek No, the car was literally playing the music through it's speakers. It says so in the article I linked to.

Comment: If the music had been running on the speakers, you would not have been able to hear it. Also, the Tesla was unpowered. Only the cameras and communication equipment had power.

Comment: Any links? Also, the music was 'Life on Mars', my bad.

Comment: `+1` Bowie started singing right after fairing separation, at only about 115 km, so there was certainly a bit of air at the time. A *very sensitive* microphone would have likely even picked it up. https://youtu.be/wbSwFU6tY1c?t=1525 More about [sound in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24204/12102).

Comment: I've just asked [What sort of ambient air density was there when/were Starman/Roadster first started playing Bowie's “Life on Mars”](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30337/12102)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that is making progress towards playing a record of Carl Sagan (and Stephen Hawking) "singing" in space.

Currently they seem to have only gotten to 28.5 km, but I have a hunch they won't stop until they can play beyond the Karman line.

You can read further in the question [What technical challenges would be playing this LP in (actual) space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17766/12102)

The "original soundtrack":