# How did Sergei Krikalev get (or build) the drum he is shown playing here?

Tags: identify-this-object, mir

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30339/12102) @horsh shows an image of Russian cosmonaut [Sergei Krikalev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Krikalev) playing what might be an improvised drum, together with cosmonaut [Sergey Volkov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Volkov_(cosmonaut)) on guitar, aboard Mir in 1989.

Is it possible to identify how this drum was improvised? Are the objects recognizable?

**note:** Krikalev is also said to be one of the [World's Most Prolific Time Traveller](https://www.universetoday.com/105650/cosmonaut-sergei-krikalev-the-worlds-most-prolific-time-traveler/)s.

[image]

Comment: very slightly related: [Which astronaut has experienced the largest relativistic shift in time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30342/12102)

Comment: The question is interesting. I can say that web search in Russian language like "игра на барабане станция мир" returns nothing relevant, unfortunately..

Comment: I may be mistaken, but the gray material on the side of the cylinder sure looks like duct tape.

Comment: @Heopps I've just put a bounty on [Why have four parabolas on a ground-side array instead of just a single large one](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30399/12102)> Have a look at the text of the bounty?