# Is printing boarding pass to space a common practice?

Tags: astronauts

I saw these boarding passes the other day in JAL museum.

Funny enough, since it's printed by JAL, which does not fly to space yet, I guess this should be considered as a correspondence flight :)

[image: Boarding tickets]
*Picture source: Own work.*

Is it a common practice to print this kind of tickets for astronauts ?

Comment: Looks like a souvenir item.  I worked with one of the JAXA crew and they had all kinds of neat stuff to give out.  It was also common to ask rookie crewmembers in the Astrovan on the way to the pad for their launch ticket.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a promotional item.  [Koichi Wakata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koichi_Wakata) launched to the ISS on a Soyuz (correctly listed as TM-11M) in November 2013 which is close to the dates on the "ticket".  The return date, however, is not close to the actual return date of May 2014.  BKN is probably supposed to be Baikonur.

I would be surprised if Japan Air Lines is actually authorized to issue tickets for Soyuz flights.

Comment: Any information wether other airlines did it ?

Comment: Boarding pass for return flight [could have been printed](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15498/#comment40853_15498) on board the ISS perhaps? :-)