# What paper size do they use on the International Space Station?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, technology, standards

We know they have at least [one printer on the ISS](https://press.hp.com/us/en/press-kits/2017/hp-envy-zero-gravity-printer.html) – that's NASA-supplied so it would be in the US Orbital Segment. Presumably there is a printer in the Russian Orbital Segment as well. (Mir [had a teletype](https://www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet88/reite88.htm).)

My question is – what paper size do they use on the ISS – A4, US Letter, or a mix? I assume that if Roscosmos has a printer they'd want to load it with A4; but would NASA use A4 in their printer so the whole of ISS uses a standard paper size? Or would they stick to US Letter since that's what NASA is used to?

(Also, I guess there is some argument that something called the "International Space Station" ought to prefer the international standard paper size.)

Comment: different but related: [Was this printer shown the ISS in 2015 built specially to work in microgravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15498/12102)

Comment: I like this question, but I can't help but wonder - what motivated you to ask it?

Comment: They use it to print out procedures, which on the ground are US letter, but I can't find anything to confirm that's what is used up there.  Cool question!

Comment: @SF Curiosity mainly. Also, I am interested in standards, and wonder if US dominance in space is going to lead to the US tendency to not use certain international standards to be exported to space and other celestial bodies. NASA and the commercial space industry presently prefer metric for anything in space (although I believe the US segment of ISS is metric for new stuff but still uses US customary for some older components), so that's one area in which it probably won't happen. But paper sizes is another.

Comment: IMO, a useful answer will _primarily_ address the _physical_ paper sizes available on the ISS, as virtually all "modern" printers can handle a plethora of formats...

Comment: Cool question! fyi I've just asked [Was the teletype machine on MIR the first printer in space? Is there a photo, and what frequencies were used?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53839/12102)

Comment: I found a Forbes and TechCrunch article that act like everything is more or less normal when it comes to the ink and the paper. The only really crazy things that had to be done to the printer included a system that prevented droplets of ink from floating off and contaminating the station. Here are the articles: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jenniferhicks/2018/04/12/see-how-this-printer-works-in-zero-gravity-on-the-international-space-station/?sh=1d4951771a12 & https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/the-international-space-station-is-getting-a-new-printer/

Comment: Since there's no answer yet, you might try asking HP.

Comment: The paper size would probably synchronized to the electronic document they produce. So if you could hunt down some document that is known to have been printed on ISS, the file would include the format information.

Comment: Is the fact that NASA has gone metric relevant here?

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch please stop making inconsequential edits to the question.  "My" is fine.  "So, my" isn't different (and I know for a fact that there are people who consider it incorrect).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although one cannot exclude other paper sizes being sometimes used, US astronauts on the ISS definitely used A4 paper.

- "Printer Paper, A4" is listed three times on this NASA [International Space Station Program Cargo Mission Contract](https://www.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/nnj010ga35c.pdf). US letter-sized paper is not mentioned.
- I can easily find ISS photos with American astronauts either holding A4 paper or it appearing in the background:

  – [astronaut Shane Kimbrough and floating red leaf lettuce on the ISS](https://www.cbc.ca/radio/quirks/mar-2-mobilizing-scientists-in-the-covid-19-fight-riding-the-covid-wave-and-more-1.5512550/salads-in-space-nasa-has-learned-to-grow-lettuce-on-the-space-station-1.5512563)

  – [Scott Kelly and Mikhail Kornienko celebrate their 300th day on the ISS](https://www.space.com/32103-yearlong-space-mission-by-the-numbers.html)

  – [Scott Kelly starts #whyspacematters contest from the ISS](https://news.un.org/en/story/2015/06/501812)

I cannot find any mention or clear images of US letter-sized paper on the ISS.

Despite being somewhat embarrassed to ask, I submitted a question to NASA about this, and several weeks later received an unhelpful boilerplate answer that just pointed me to various ISS websites.

Comment: Great reference!

Comment: Great source!  I also found "Color Printer Paper (6 Hole, 1/4" Dia.)" on page 421, Green Record Book 8 x 10.5 lined, Metric Pad Assembly Green, Drawing Paper 14x17 white (page 453), and 8x5 inch toilet paper.  I'm skeptical of IDing A4 paper instead of letter in a photo (A4 is 8.3 x 11.7 inches, versus 8.5 x 11 inch letter paper) but it is SO GOOD to have a proper answer to this question now

Comment: Thanks @Erin-Anne. I agree the visual identification might not be 100% certain, but I actually measured (i.e. counted pixels) the sizes. The paper in the Scott Kelly images seems clearly inconsistent with letter-sized and consistent with A4.  The Shane Kimbrough paper size is more consistent with A4 than letter sized, but it isn't unambiguous since there are several overlapping and imperfectly aligned sheets on the pad.